# How to determine once all async readFile() calls have completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looping over file directories and for each location I am reading the files in this directory with an async `fs.readFile()`. How can I best determine if all the async `readFile()` calls have completed?

Comment: A promise library would help here - have you checked out `bluebird` ? https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: How would that help in this case? Doesn't that still only deal with individual async calls?

Comment: Nah - you can use Bluebird for looping async calls and mapping the results - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051467/why-is-this-fs-readfile-loop-not-pushing-its-results-to-my-array

Comment: Ok thanks - that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general strategy is to keep track of the number of files you have already read by incrementing a shared counter from `fs.readFile` callbacks. Then, when this counter equals the total number of files, you know you are done. For example:

```
function readFiles(paths, callback) {
  var processed = 0,
      total = paths.length;

  // holds results (file contents) in the same order as paths
  var results = new Array(total);

  // asynchronously read all files
  for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; ++i) {
    fs.readFile(paths[i], doneFactory(i));
  }

  // factory for generating callbacks to fs.readFile
  // and closing over the index i
  function doneFactory(i) {
    // this is a callback to fs.readFile
    return function done(err, result) {
      // save the result under the correct index
      results[i] = result;

      // if we are all done, callback with all results
      if (++processed === total) {
        callback(results);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used like:

```
readFiles(['one.txt', 'two.txt'], function (results) {
  var oneTxtContents = results[0];
  var twoTxtContents = results[1];
});
```

---

If you are on Node 0.11.13 or higher, you can also make use of native promises, and in particular `Promise.all`, which takes an array of promises and waits for all of them to be resolved:

```
function readFiles(paths) {
  // for each path, generate a promise which is resolved
  // with the contents of the file when the file is read
  var promises = paths.map(function (path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      fs.readFile(path, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

which can be used like:

```
readFiles(['one.txt', 'two.txt']).then(function (results) {
  var oneTxtContents = results[0];
  var twoTxtContents = results[1];
});
```

---

Finally, there are a number of libraries which make this (rather common) task easier.

For callback-based parallel asynchronous tasks, you can use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library:

```
async.map(['one.txt', 'two.txt'], fs.readFile, function (err, results) {
  var oneTxtContents = results[0];
  var twoTxtContents = results[1];
});
```

For Promise-based parallel asynchronous tasks, you can use a Promise library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which contains utilities for "promisification" of Node-style functions like `fs.readFile`:

```
// this is not the only way to achieve this with Q!
Q.all(['one.txt', 'two.txt'].map(function (path) {
  // call "promisified" version of fs.readFile, return promise
  return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, path);
})).then(function (results) {
  // all promises have been resolved
  var oneTxtContents = results[0];
  var twoTxtContents = results[1];
});
```

Comment: I ended up using tymeJV's suggestion of bluebird and made use of its `.map()` which essentially does what you have described.